# Using proxys with urllib Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I want to use proxies with urllib of python 3. However I am running into problems.

```
import urllib

Header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X  vAppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

URL = "https://www.sth.com/"

proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http' :'52.170.21.0:3128'})
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

req = urllib.request.Request( url=URL ,headers=Header, data=None)

ans_object = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

First problem: I cant find a guide on how to use an IP adress in the ProxyHandler. So I dont know if this is even SUPPOSED to work. However assuming it SHOULD work:

I dont know how to chekc wether my request uses a proxy or not. I tried the (UNDOCUMENTED!!!!!!! theres no entrance for this method in the offical docs) method .has_proxy() and got a FALSE as return.

So how do I check if my script is using a proxy?

I also tried to use the request.set_proxy(host, type) method.
According to the documentation it should set the request.host to "host" and the request.selector to the full url. However when I use

```
req.set_proxy('52.170.21.0:3128','https')
```

I only get "/" as a result for req.selector.

I find the official documentation severally lacking.

Thank you for any help